# How to parse for occurences based on inputs in the same file

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
event1           foo_id1
event1           foo_id2
event1           foo_id4
event1           foo_id6
event1           foo_id7
event1           foo_id8
event1           foo_id8
event1           foo_id1
event1           foo_id4

event2           foo_id1
event2           foo_id2
event2           foo_id3
event2           foo_id4
event2           foo_id5
event2           foo_id6
event2           foo_id8
event2           foo_id9
event2           foo_id11
```

The above information is available as a file in S3 under a certain bucket (say `s3://hadoop.mycompany.com/bucket1/foo1.txt`).

All events have `foo_ids`. For all events in "`event2`", I would like to know how many times those `foo_id`(s) occur in `event1`.

e.g. in the above case,

```
foo_id1=2
foo_id2=1
foo_id3=0
foo_id4=2
foo_id5=0
foo_id6=1
foo_id8=2
foo_id9=0
foo_id11=0
```

How to write a hive script to return the data in the expected format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this can be accomplished using following hive script:

1. First you need to create hive external table using this command

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE events (event STRING, foo STRING)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   LOCATION 's3n://hadoop.mycompany.com/bucket1/';
2. Run following query

   SELECT e2.foo, count(e1.foo)
   FROM events e2 LEFT OUTER JOIN events e1 ON e1.foo = e2.foo AND e1.event = 'event1'
   WHERE e2.event = 'event2'
   GROUP BY e2.foo;

You should get results that you need, something like this:

```
foo_id1  2
foo_id11 0
foo_id2  1
foo_id3  0
foo_id4  2
foo_id5  0
foo_id6  1
foo_id8  2
foo_id9  0
```

Hope this solves your problem.